# What evolutionary algorithms are there that model epigenetics?

Tags: reference-request, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, genetic-programming, evolutionary-computation

What evolutionary algorithms are there that model or incorporate some notion of [epigenetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics)? What are the pros/cons of those approaches? Are there vast insufficiencies or wide-open questions about their usefulness?

Answer (score 7):

Over the last few years, evolutionary computation research has shown increasing interest in including some aspect of epigenetics. For example:

- A 2008 paper by [Tanev and Yuta](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025508002880)
- Work from [Lee Spector's genetic programming group](http://faculty.hampshire.edu/lspector/pubs/Epigenetics_2015_GECCO_final.pdf)
- A recent paper by [Ricalde and Banzhaf](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-30668-1_9)

Comment: It would really be nice if you could also (at least briefly) address the other question "What are the pros/cons of those approaches?".